# How to resolve the dll conflict of installing Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed?

Tags: dll, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm migrating my WinPhone8.1 project to UWP and I found some incompatibility of the behaviors in the xaml. It seems that I need to install **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed** and **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Native**. However, after installation, I got compilation error like this:An assembly with the same simple name **'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references**... I think xaml.interactivity is provided by the framework and I cann't see it in the references in solution explorer. I'm wondering if any one can give some idea on this. Here is a screenshot of the references excluding my own dlls.
[image]

Code snippet

```
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior
                EventName="ItemClick">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding ViewSomeCommand}"
                    InputConverter="{StaticResource ItemClickedToSomeConverter}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: I see it.  The Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity assembly exists both in these Nuget packages as well as the Universal Windows package.  Not the same version number.  Probably best to click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/issues) for the best guidance.

Comment: @HansPassant it seems no one has asked this question, yet...

Comment: Click the button, don't just look at it.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought it is the conflict between framework's dll and these twoo dlls, but it turns out that once I removed Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed, this compilation error message is gone. Though some new issues came out...thanks

Comment: For a windows 8.1 app, the behaviors SDK(XAML) version is 12.0, for an UWP app, we use [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors). For your scenario, you will need to remove the "Behaviors SDK(XAML)" from your project's reference and install the "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed", if there are still errors after this work, please post your code with error.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I edited my quesiton and added a screenshot of solution explorer, there seems no SDK (XAML). The interesting thing is that installing Uwp.Managed will cause the conflict while if I only install Uwp.Native will not cause the problem, however if I use Native, I cannot go the page with the behaviors, I also updated my question with code snippet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Only install  Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i tried it and worked with me.